# Как правильно эту строку в песне кота Леопольда оформить?

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно эту строку в песне кота Леопольда оформить?

> Лечу, лечу, лечу — не знаю куда.

> Лечу, лечу, лечу не знаю куда.

> Лечу, лечу, лечу, не знаю куда.

Comment: Слова в ЭТОЙ и всех ПОСЛЕДУЮЩИХ песенках смотрите в текстах песенок. Если тексты разные, то обозначьте проблему, как вы ее видите, и предложите свое решение.

Comment: Инверсированный порядок слов в названии вопроса выглядит необоснованным. Нарушение информационного стиля.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ВМЕСТО ВСТУПЛЕНИЯ**

С песенкой Леопольда, конечно, **проблемы** — нормального варианта записанного текста не найдешь. Просто садись — и всё переписывай.

**Как тут поступить?** Автор вопроса находит проблемное предложение. Да, действительно, проблемное! Он не знает, что поставить: запятую, тире, пробел? В этом случае нужно **предложить свое решение**, а проблему хотя бы как-то обозначить. **Но ничего этого нет:** участник с репутацией 5К ждет, когда ему помогут.

Наш (и мой любимейший) участник дает ответ. **Прекрасное решение,** нет вопросов! Я его выберу по интонации, я его докажу по грамматике и правилам. А здесь — опыт редактора, чувство языка и интуиция. Вот какие у нас люди!

А с чем остаются **другие участники** и гости форума? Ответ указан, но решение **не обосновано** правилами или грамматикой, как это нужно  обычному пользователю языка. И я попробую это сделать.

**РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ**

*Лечу, лечу, лечу — **не знаю куда**.*

1. **Грамматика**

Это БСП, отношения присоединительные, но с оттенком противопоставления: лечу, но не знаю куда. Я их так определяю. Конечно же для их обозначения нужен **сильный знак**, то есть тире. Без знака никак нельзя,  а запятая не подойдет. Мое решение тоже **короткое.**

2. **Правила**

Правила нужны? Я бы все **по Лопатину (по блокам)** решала бы, да только в каждом блоке здесь по одному предложению. А так удобно: проблемный знак выбираем по отношениям между частями. А в правилах для БСП требуется найти **что-то подходящее.** Остановимся на присоединении, **[пункт 9 по Розенталю](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151):**

Если вторая часть бессоюзного сложного предложения представляет собой **присоединительное** предложение, перед ней ставится тире: *На стене ни одного образа — **дурной знак*** (Л.); Мы видим, что во второй части БСП высказано суждение по поводу первой части, а в нашем случае **аналогичная** ситуация.

Answer (score 1):

Третий вариант: а чего запятые-то плодить (корректорская приговорка).

Второй: лечу не знаю - это олбанский: однородные члены.

Первый: вот оно оно!

***Лечу, лечу, лечу — не знаю куда.***